# InDesign data merge template not following path

Tags: adobe-indesign, data-merge

I'm creating a curved path which is being used as a placeholder for data merge content. I create the path, click on it, then double-click the field in the data merge window.

It places `<<fieldName>>` text in the frame, but it's not aligned to the path.

It works fine when I manually add text-on-path or "fill with sample content", so I've missed something.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the text path insertion point and apply your tag. It's likely that you selected the parent frame instead:
[image]